# Show that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a noetherian local ring and $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ be its unique maximal ideal. Then $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is a $A/\mathfrak{m}$ vector space. I want to show such space is finite dimensional. To do this, I'll use the following fact:

> If $k$ is a field and $V$ is a vector space over $k$ then TFAE: 1) $V$ is finite dimensional. 2) $V$ satisfies ACC 3) $V$ satisfies DCC

My question is 1. what is the form of subspace of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$? I think it's of the form $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ where $\mathfrak{n}\subset A$ is an ideal such that $\mathfrak{m}^2\subset\mathfrak{n}\subset\mathfrak{m}$. 2. If the subspace is of the form I wrote before, then being $A$ is noetherian almost immediately shows $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has ACC. My question is I don't use anything about local crucially. Can I drop the 'local' condition?

Comment: For your reference, there is [a similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368866/why-are-quotient-modules-m-mathfrakmm-over-residue-fields-a-mathfrak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If $A$ is Noetherian but not necessarily local, and $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal, then $A_{\mathfrak m}$ is a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak mA_{\mathfrak m}$, and $\mathfrak mA_{\mathfrak m}/ \mathfrak m^2A_{\mathfrak m}$ identifies with $\mathfrak m/ \mathfrak m^2$ as $A/\mathfrak m = A_{\mathfrak m}/\mathfrak m A_{\mathfrak m}$ vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still, I have question. 1. Is it trivial that the subspace of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is of the form I wrote above? 2. My question is why 'local' is necessary in the statement. I didn't use anything about locality in my argument

Comment: 1 .  Yes, I think that is trivial.  2 .  Local is not necessary

Comment: At least when $A$ is not noetherian then the krull dimension isn't related to $\dim_{A/m}(m/m^2)$, try with $A=k[t^a,a\in \Bbb{Q}_{\ge 1}]$ and $m=A-k$ then $m/m^2$ is infinite dimensional and $A_m$ has dimension 1. Try with $R=k[t^a,a\in \Bbb{Q}_{>0}],m=A-k$ then $m/m^2 = 0$ and $R_m$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: @reuns thanks I didn't realize that

Comment: What is a short argument to show that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ and $\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}} / \mathfrak{m}^2 A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ are isomorphic as $A/\mathfrak{m}$-vector spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Any $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$ subspace of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is a sub $A$-module of $A/\mathfrak{m}^2$.

If $\dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)=\infty$ then a strictly increasing sequence of subspaces gives a strictly increasing sequence of ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{m}^2$ so that $A$ is not Noetherian.